# Turn on DDL auditing

Tags: oracle, audit, audit-trail

How to audit DDL statements in oracle 10g and clear audited data before 30days... Thank you.

**IN EDITION:**

**How** can I turn on auditing on "ALTER TABLE" statement? when I run AUDIT TABLE; or AUDIT ALTER TABLE; or AUDIT ALTER ANY TABLE; Audited information can't be seen in AUD$ or DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL views.(Just event when system user alters table is written,but there is no record for HR user)
why????

Comment: I have edited concrete question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/Auditing_10gR2.php

Answer (score 0):

Check if the audit option is enabled:

```
 select value
 from v$parameter
 where name = 'audit_trail';
```

if the result is 'NONE' (which is default) then the audit is not turned on.

To enable audit you must set the AUDIT_TRAIL initialization parameter in the database initialization parameter file. The parameter must be set to one of the following values: 'DB', 'XML', 'DB,EXTENDED', 'XML,EXTENDED', 'OS'.

For managing audit trail records you can use the [DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11062_01/admin.1023/e11059/avadm_app_d_audit_mgmt.htm) package.

Comment: It is turned on and the value is DB..I wrote "Just event when system user alters table is written,but there is no record for HR user"  I mean for system user the recored is created for HR is not created.